# Openshift MySql Emoji support

Tags: mysql, openshift, emoji, utf8mb4, cartridge

I'm trying to support emoji on Openshift MySql cartridge. I've set the UTF8mb4 character set following a few guides, but it doesn't seem to work. When i try to INSERT an emoji in a VARCHAR field, it instead stores "????".
Is this an Openshift problem? Does anybody know how to fully support emoji?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple question marks usually means that the table/column is declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  See `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to check.

That is only one of 4 places that you need to specify utf8mb4:

- Presumably the Emoji bytes are utf8 already.
- `SET NAMES utf8mb4` -- or whatever the equivalent in openshift/cartridge is for establishing the connection.
- The table/column must be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.
- Html needs `<meta ... charset=UTF-8>`

Comment: Thanks Rick James. I've always had UTF8mb4 in tables and columns, and set the NAMES correctly...I don't know why Openshift MySql doesn't seem to accept utf8mb4!

Comment: Grrr...  Another 3rd party software getting in the way.